# Adding a count to prior cell value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

in Pandas I am looking to add a value in one column 'B' depending on the boolean values from another column 'A'. So if 'A' is True then start counting (i.e. adding a one each new line) as long as 'A' is false. When 'A' is True reset and start counting again. I managed to do this with a 'for' loop but this is very time consuming. I am wondering if there is no more time efficient solution?

the result should look like this:

```
Date     A      B 
01.2010 False   0
02.2010 True    1
03.2010 False   2
04.2010 False   3
05.2010 True    1
06.2010 False   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print df
    Date      A
0  1.201  False
1  1.201   True
2  1.201  False
3  2.201   True
4  3.201  False
5  4.201  False
6  5.201   True
7  6.201  False
roll = df.A.cumsum()
print roll
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
Name: A, dtype: int32

df['B'] = df.groupby(roll).cumcount() + 1
#if in first values are False, output is 0
df.loc[roll == 0 , 'B'] = 0   
print df
    Date      A  B
0  1.201  False  0
1  1.201   True  1
2  1.201  False  2
3  2.201   True  1
4  3.201  False  2
5  4.201  False  3
6  5.201   True  1
7  6.201  False  2
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I got the solution from another post similar to this:

```
rolling_count = 0
def set_counter(val):

  if val == False: 

    global rolling_count  
    rolling_count +=1

  else:

    val == True
    rolling_count = 1

  return rolling_count

df['B'] = df['A'].map(set_counter)
```

Comment: I test timing of both solution and first your solution has different output - first row has `1` in your solution, not `0` in column `B`. And if check timings with `len(df)=7000`: `%timeit (al(df1)) 100 loops, best of 3: 3.75 ms per loop` vs `%timeit (jez(df)) 100 loops, best of 3: 2.29 ms per loop`. Last you lost 2 points for accepting. But it is up to you, if think it is better accept your solution.

Comment: @jezrael, many thanks. Coming from Excel/vba I found my presented solution more intuitive and it did the job in real life. Nonetheless your solution is more pandaesque. I still have to study the difference of cumcount() and cumsum().

Comment: Thank you for accepting too. I think better is use function of pandas if possible, which are more optimalized as custom function.